# Appending dropdown menu to specific menuitem in Kendo UI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created menubar in kendo UI as follows

```
@Html.Kendo().Menu().Name("NavigationMenu").Items(items =>
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                foreach (SearchHub.Models.Shared.SubModule s in ViewBag.SubModule)
                {
                    items.Add().HtmlAttributes(new { id = s.controller }).Text(s.Title).Action("Index", s.controller);

                }
                items.Add().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "TD" }).Text("Training").Action("Index", "TD")  ;

            }
            else
            {
                items.Add().Text("Login").Action("Index", "Login");
            }
        }) ;
```

This is viewing as below:

[image]

I want to have drop down menu `Teacher` and `Student` when i keep mouse over Traning Menu item.

For that i tried to append some `<ul> <li>` to :

```
  items.Add().HtmlAttributes(new { id = s.controller }).Text(s.Title).Action("Index", s.controller).Append... ;
```

but .Append is not function over here for menu item.

I want same functionality as we do in simple asp.net-jquery to `SlideDown()`

How can i have drop down menu item when i have mouse over Training???

Please help me, I am new to MVC4 and Kendo UI in asp.net